# Laravel Registration Error: FatalErrorException in AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php line 41: Call to a member function validator() on null

Tags: php, laravel, registration

I am brand new to Laravel and working through the Laracasts Fundamentals videos, and on #15 I am trying to set up Registration but when I enter my details, the above error shows. I've tried changing my constructor from:

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

to:

```
        public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }
```

however I then get an error saying the Guard class doesn't exist, and I can't find any code for the Guard class.

I have had some issues with missing files in my package, so this is probably the problem. I had a second project using laravel so I merged the files to try and get the missing files but there may still be some missing but with so many files, I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: If there are missing files then it seems like the way to go is fresh install Laravel again.

Comment: @Stah I just tried that, again merging my old files with new files straight from GitHub (in case it was a problem with the installer) and now it doesn't work at all XD

Comment: Uh, how about completely fresh and add everything back once it's confirmed working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you say `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;` at top of the file?

Are both installations you merged the same version of Laravel?

Comment: I did, yes. And then it did the same for Registrar so I added that too, and then when I refresh the form doesn't even show up, just "BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 745:
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar] is not instantiable." And that's where I gave up and came here. Reinstalling proved fruitless, there is no view/auth folder again which had given me problems before (which I fixed). I don't know why I'm only getting these partial installs.

Comment: Laravel 5 or 5.1? The video you referred to is on 5 which is a different folder structure then 5.1.